# Color Items with functions in PowerApps

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula

On the following video :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BnYe_7fpZRM&list=PLCGGtLsUjhm2bonhBZuEhZU72QkFjOpc6&index=1

what is the difference between :

- ColorValue (minute 8:36) and
- ThisItem.Color

Answer (score 1):

That video is a bit old now but still very relevant.

**ThisItem** refers to the current item/row in *a Gallery*, for example.

In the case that your datasource is SharePoint and you have a column called Title, **ThisItem.Title** will return the Title for each of the rows in your ShaerPoint List

In Shane's video he has a Column called Color in his SharePoint site and as I can see that column stores a Text value - colours names.

ColorValue is a function within the Power FX functions that take a text parameters and returns a "colour object" to Power Apps - for example:

```
ColorValue( "Chocolate" )
```

is equivalent to

```
ColorValue( "#d2691e" )
```

and also

```
RGBA( 210, 105, 30, 1 )
```

[Link to Microsoft Color documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-colors#built-in-colors)